# How does amplitude induce pitch shift?

Tags: sound, hearing

I am curious to know how sound intensity influences on perceived pitch. For instance, if loudness is increased, a high pitch will be perceived higher while a low pitch will be perceived lower. Why does this interaction between loudness and pitch occur to human auditory?

Comment: We’ve had this question on here before: https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/45838/24007 but, as far as I know, no one knows for sure. Our brains are still hiding secrets.

Comment: @Timinycricket Thank you for the suggestion. This helps a lot!